# IIB - client connection to integration node

Tags: ibm-integration-bus

I want to check number of active/inactive connection (on node port) at any point of time to my IIB broker.

basically there are multiple clients which connects to integration node (port) to verify if node is available. we suspect not all connections are closed properly.

Need suggestion. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try below command in console:

mqsireportproperties  -c JMSProviders -o AllReportableEntityNames -r

Answer (score 0):

Using netstat command can show connection information. Grep on Linux and findstr command can be used to filter the output for certain port.